# insert same record multiple times based on the given count

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, count, recursive-query

```
TYPE   COUNT
---     --
ABC     3
EDC     4
FDC     2
```

I want to insert ABC thrice, EDC four times, FDC twice in a table using single SQL, is it possible?
The output of the query should insert into the following table with the following entries.

```
TYPE
----
ABC
ABC
ABC
EDC
EDC
EDC
EDC
FDC
FDC
FDC
```

Thanks

Comment: This kind of problem tends to be symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically use a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select type, cnt from mytable t
    union all
    select type, cnt - 1 from cte where cnt > 1
)
select type from cte
```

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dfe942ef82c77535c7df2af523164ebd)**; the syntax works in both Postgres and MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use `generate_series()`:

```
insert into target_table (some_column)
select t.type
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1,t."count")
order by t.type
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.